# Error ,,Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.4.0-87-generic (x86_64)” when installing Synaptic on Ubuntu 16.04.3. Or it is a normal error?

Tags: software-installation, kernel, dpkg, synaptic

1.Do you recomend using sudo apt-get upgrade command before installing Synaptic through terminal?

2.(in the future): Before uninstalling an old module version which was ACTIVE on this kernel, should i manually set it to inactive ? Or ubuntu does this by default with an OK exit in all cases?

3.please observe the 2 errors:

```
a. Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel
b. error processing package oem
```

4.whats worse: being a 3rd party, could not report the ,,serious problem”

below, I will post the output of my terminal. Is this normal ?

```
Setting up   oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms (0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Removing old oem-audio-hda-daily-0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1 DKMS files...

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  oem-audio-hda-daily
Version: 0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1
Kernel:  4.4.0-23-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------
Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.
DKMS: uninstall completed.
------------------------------
Deleting module version: 0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new oem-audio-hda-daily-0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 4.4.0-87-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.4.0-87-generic

ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms.0.crash'

Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.4.0-87-generic (x86_64)

Consult /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/make.log for more information.

dpkg: error processing package oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up sgml-data (2.0.10) ...
Setting up libept1.5.0:amd64 (1.1+nmu3) ...
Setting up librarian0 (0.8.1-6) ...
Setting up synaptic (0.83) ...
Processing triggers for sgml-base (1.26+nmu4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up docbook-xml (4.5-7.3) ...
Processing triggers for sgml-base (1.26+nmu4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up rarian-compat (0.8.1-6) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.47ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Thanks in advance.

---

@heynnema
..........

```
DKMS make.log for oem-audio-hda-daily-0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1 for kernel 4.4.0-87-generic (x86_64)
Wednesday 9 August 2017, 16:30:04 +0100
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-87-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-87-generic'
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hda_bind.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hda_codec.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hda_jack.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hda_auto_parser.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hda_sysfs.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hda_controller.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hda_proc.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hda_hwdep.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hda_beep.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/snd-hda-codec.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hda_generic.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/snd-hda-codec-generic.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/patch_realtek.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/snd-hda-codec-realtek.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/patch_cmedia.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/snd-hda-codec-cmedia.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/patch_analog.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/snd-hda-codec-analog.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/patch_sigmatel.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/snd-hda-codec-idt.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/patch_si3054.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/snd-hda-codec-si3054.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/patch_cirrus.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/snd-hda-codec-cirrus.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/patch_ca0110.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/snd-hda-codec-ca0110.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/patch_ca0132.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/snd-hda-codec-ca0132.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/patch_conexant.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/snd-hda-codec-conexant.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/patch_via.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/snd-hda-codec-via.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/patch_hdmi.o
/var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/patch_hdmi.c: In function ‘register_i915_notifier’:
/var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/patch_hdmi.c:2338:38: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  spec->i915_audio_ops.pin_eld_notify = intel_pin_eld_notify;
                                      ^
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hda_eld.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/snd-hda-codec-hdmi.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hda_intel.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/snd-hda-intel.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hdacore/hda_bus_type.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hdacore/hdac_bus.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hdacore/hdac_device.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hdacore/hdac_sysfs.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hdacore/hdac_regmap.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hdacore/hdac_controller.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hdacore/hdac_stream.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hdacore/array.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hdacore/hdmi_chmap.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hdacore/trace.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hdacore/hdac_i915.o
/var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hdacore/hdac_i915.c: In function ‘snd_hdac_sync_audio_rate’:
/var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hdacore/hdac_i915.c:215:9: error: too few arguments to function ‘acomp->ops->sync_audio_rate’
  return acomp->ops->sync_audio_rate(acomp->dev, port, rate);
         ^
/var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hdacore/hdac_i915.c: In function ‘snd_hdac_acomp_get_eld’:
/var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hdacore/hdac_i915.c:252:47: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘acomp->ops->get_eld’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  return acomp->ops->get_eld(acomp->dev, port, audio_enabled,
                                               ^
/var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hdacore/hdac_i915.c:252:47: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘bool * {aka _Bool *}’
/var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hdacore/hdac_i915.c:253:8: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘acomp->ops->get_eld’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        buffer, max_bytes);
        ^
/var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hdacore/hdac_i915.c:253:8: note: expected ‘bool * {aka _Bool *}’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
/var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hdacore/hdac_i915.c:253:16: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘acomp->ops->get_eld’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
        buffer, max_bytes);
                ^
/var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hdacore/hdac_i915.c:253:16: note: expected ‘unsigned char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
/var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hdacore/hdac_i915.c:252:9: error: too few arguments to function ‘acomp->ops->get_eld’
  return acomp->ops->get_eld(acomp->dev, port, audio_enabled,
         ^
/var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hdacore/hdac_i915.c: In function ‘snd_hdac_sync_audio_rate’:
/var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hdacore/hdac_i915.c:216:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
/var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hdacore/hdac_i915.c: In function ‘snd_hdac_acomp_get_eld’:
/var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hdacore/hdac_i915.c:254:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
scripts/Makefile.build:258: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hdacore/hdac_i915.o' failed
make[3]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hdacore/hdac_i915.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:403: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hdacore' failed
make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/hdacore] Error 2
Makefile:1420: recipe for target '_module_/var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-87-generic'
Makefile:53: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Synaptic is not related. The problem is with `oem-audio-hda-daily`. Is it a Dell laptop with preinstalled Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Yes Pilot6. Dell Inspiron 5567 with preinstalled 14.04 LTS

Comment: Edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `cat /var/lib/dkms/oem-audio-hda-daily/0.201612080732~ubuntu16.04.1/build/make.log`. Start new comments to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I have posted the requested output below, as an answer, cause it”s too long. I did not remove the OEM package just yet.

Comment: Are you running 16.04.2 or .3? If so, they use a newer kernel than 16.04 or 16.04.1, and this dkms kernel module won't compile with the newer kernel. I'd go to the Dell web site with your service ID #, or your model/serial #, and see if they have a newer module available. If you don't see one, I'd call them and ask the question.

Comment: @heynnema ... (1) Now, it”s 16.04.3 LTS. But when i bought it, it was 14.04 (2) Should i go for purging oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms as Pilot6 said ?

Comment: @heynnema  upon entering the command cat,  i get this: No such file or directory.

Comment: I would follow my suggestion first. You might get a newer piece of software to replace the failing version... and if none of that works, follow Pilot6's advice... but I don't know what functionality you might lose if that module isn't there and working.

Comment: @heynnema ...  maybe downgrade to 16.04 ? what do you think ?

Comment: I'd still follow my earlier suggestion about contacting the Dell folks via their web site, and/or by phone.

Comment: @heynnema 2)) or, just renounce at Synaptic, and do it and learning the system by heart ? however, all above being said:  what other problems should i expect in the future if i stay on 16.04.3 ?

Comment: Synaptic doesn't have anything to do with this kernel module. Any time you move forward you risk that some software falls behind and requires an update too... so I'll suggest this... for the third time... contact Dell first.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this OEM package. It is not supported by Ubuntu 16.04.

```
sudo apt purge oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms
```

Comment: roger Pilot. i will come back with an output

Comment: I don't need the output. It should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

See launchpad bug **1755309 i915_component.h has wrong prototype for function pin_eld_notify causing HDMI audio driver build problems**.  The problem with the 4.4 kernel (default for 16.04) is that Canonical grabbed a release candidate for /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-xxx/include/drm/i915_component.h, and didn't notice that the final version removed a parameter on pin_eld_notify, causing the dkms rebuild to fail.  You could edit out the third parameter "pipe" and the compile will succeed.  This worked up to kernel version 4.4.0-140 or so, when an interface change caused many other problems -- fixed with the later kernels then available.